# Cypress string variable condition

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm write Cypress script is say js, but I have some issue about variable checking
the code is like this

```
var baseUrl = Cypress.config('baseUrl');
// baseUrl can return http://developmachine1.localhost/test

I want to do simple condition
 if (baseUrl.contains('localhost'))
  {
     do something ...
  }
else 
{
   do something ..
}
```

but it will throw `TypeError : baseUrl.contains is not a function`
can I know to do it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The JS function for checking if a [string contains another string is `includes`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
if (baseUrl.includes('localhost')) {
  // code
} ...
```